# TSearchRec Delphi backward

Tags: file, delphi, directory-structure

I don't know exactly how to explain my question. Here is my try to explain: the function FindNext(SearchRec) will get me the next file from a directory. In my application I am looking sometimes go to backward a few files from my current SearchRec index. So how can I do that?

So I am looking for the oppose of FindNext(SearchRec) a function like FindBackward(SearchRec)

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: In that case, you might consider using IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles which will return a complete list of the files you are looking for in one function call, and then you can do as you please with the resulting TStringDynArray of filenames.

Comment: This will be filesystem-sensitive.  I don't think that `FindFirst/FindNext` are guaranteed to return results in any particular order besides what the FS enumerator returns.  That NTFS returns things in a generally alphabetical order is a side effect of its implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own function. Here is the code which works very well for me and it is very efficient for thousands of files(because it doesn't slow my playback algorithm).

```
Procedure GetBackward(var SRInitial:TSearchRec; iForwardSpeed:integer);
var SR:TSearchRec;
    iIndex:integer;
    vLastFiles:Array of String;
begin
   SetLength(vLastFiles,Trunc(iForwardSpeed));

   FindFirst(sPath+'*.txt',faAnyFile,SR);
   while (FindNext(SR) = 0)and(SR.Name <> SRInitial.Name) do
   begin
      for iIndex := 0 to high(vLastFiles)-1 do
         vLastFiles[iIndex]:=vLast[iIndex+1];
      vLastFiles[high(vLastFiles)]:=SR.Name;
   end;

   //Fewer than ForwardSpeed
   if vLastFiles[0] = '' then
   begin
     Exit;
   end;

   FindClose(SR);

   FindClose(SRInitial);
   FindFirst(sPath+'*.'+cbType.Text,faAnyFile,SRInitial);
   while (FindNext(SRInitial) = 0)and(SRInitial.Name <> vLastFiles[0]) do
         ;

end;
```

The function was modified.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such function. You'll need to keep track of previous hits in a list, say, and do the back tracking using that list.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to place them in an array of TSearchRec

```
SearchRecArr:array of TSearchRec;
```

Then when you reach a certain file, get the SearchRec that you need from the Array.

for example, this is an example where I placed in some folder 3 text files of names (z, z1, & z2).
then If I reached 'z2.txt' I will read SearchRec 2 steps backwards:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SearchRec:TSearchRec;
  SearchRecArr:array of TSearchRec;
  i:integer;
begin
  i:=-1;
  if FindFirst('C:\Users\zeina.shehab\Desktop\New folder\z*.txt',faAnyFile,SearchRec)=0 then
  begin
    repeat
      SetLength(SearchRecArr,length(SearchRecArr)+1);
      SearchRecArr[high(SearchRecArr)]:=SearchRec;

      inc(i);   
      if SearchRec.Name='z2.txt' then
        caption:=SearchRecArr[i-2].Name;
    until (FindNext(SearchRec)<>0);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ohh, my favourite anti-pattern, `SetLength(SearchRecArr,length(SearchRecArr)+1)`. I'd prefer to see `TList<TSearchRec>`.

Comment: is TList<TSearchRec> faster than dynamic array? (which is using SetLength)

Comment: `TList<TSearchRec>` uses a dynamic array internally but with fewer heap reallocations. Of course, I'd expect that walking the file system will be much more significant than a few heap allocs. So I'd be surprised to see a difference in performance.

Comment: `TList<T>` uses a smarter growth algorithm to minimize reallocations.  Nothing you can't do yourself with a bit of smarts around the `SetLength` calls.  Unless `TArray<T>` has some wildly different implementation than a regular dynamic array does, but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @afrazier They are the same at implementation level, even if not assignment compatible.